# H2O machine learning platform for Python incurs EnvironmentError while building models

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, h2o

I am new to h2o machine learning platform and having the below issue while trying to build models.

When i was trying to build 5 GBM models with a not so large dataset, it has the following error:

```
gbm Model Build Progress: [##################################################] 100%

gbm Model Build Progress: [##################################################] 100%

gbm Model Build Progress: [##################################################] 100%

gbm Model Build Progress: [##################################################] 100%

gbm Model Build Progress: [#################                                 ] 34%

EnvironmentErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-e74b34df2f1a> in <module>()
     13     params_model={'x': features_pca_all, 'y': response, 'training_frame': train_holdout_pca_hex, 'validation_frame':              validation_holdout_pca_hex, 'ntrees': ntree, 'max_depth':depth, 'min_rows': min_rows, 'learn_rate': 0.005}
     14 
---> 15     gbm_model=h2o.gbm(**params_model)
     16 
     17     #store model

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o.pyc in gbm(x, y, validation_x, validation_y, training_frame, model_id, distribution, tweedie_power, ntrees, max_depth, min_rows, learn_rate, nbins, nbins_cats, validation_frame, balance_classes, max_after_balance_size, seed, build_tree_one_node, nfolds, fold_column, fold_assignment, keep_cross_validation_predictions, score_each_iteration, offset_column, weights_column, do_future, checkpoint)
   1058   parms = {k:v for k,v in locals().items() if k in ["training_frame", "validation_frame", "validation_x", "validation_y", "offset_column", "weights_column", "fold_column"] or v is not None}
   1059   parms["algo"]="gbm"
-> 1060   return h2o_model_builder.supervised(parms)
   1061 
   1062 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o_model_builder.pyc in supervised(kwargs)
     28   algo  = kwargs["algo"]
     29   parms={k:v for k,v in kwargs.items() if (k not in ["x","y","validation_x","validation_y","algo"] and v is not None) or k=="validation_frame"}
---> 30   return supervised_model_build(x,y,vx,vy,algo,offsets,weights,fold_column,parms)
     31 
     32 def unsupervised_model_build(x,validation_x,algo_url,kwargs): return _model_build(x,None,validation_x,None,algo_url,None,None,None,kwargs)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o_model_builder.pyc in supervised_model_build(x, y, vx, vy, algo, offsets, weights, fold_column, kwargs)
     16   if not is_auto_encoder and y is None: raise ValueError("Missing response")
     17   if vx is not None and vy is None:     raise ValueError("Missing response validating a supervised model")
---> 18   return _model_build(x,y,vx,vy,algo,offsets,weights,fold_column,kwargs)
     19 
     20 def supervised(kwargs):

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o_model_builder.pyc in _model_build(x, y, vx, vy, algo, offsets, weights, fold_column, kwargs)
     86   do_future = kwargs.pop("do_future") if "do_future" in kwargs else False
     87   future_model = H2OModelFuture(H2OJob(H2OConnection.post_json("ModelBuilders/"+algo, **kwargs), job_type=(algo+" Model Build")), x)
---> 88   return future_model if do_future else _resolve_model(future_model, **kwargs)
     89 
     90 def _resolve_model(future_model, **kwargs):

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o_model_builder.pyc in _resolve_model(future_model, **kwargs)
     89 
     90 def _resolve_model(future_model, **kwargs):
---> 91   future_model.poll()
     92   if '_rest_version' in kwargs.keys(): model_json = H2OConnection.get_json("Models/"+future_model.job.dest_key, _rest_version=kwargs['_rest_version'])["models"][0]
     93   else:                                model_json = H2OConnection.get_json("Models/"+future_model.job.dest_key)["models"][0]

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\model\model_future.pyc in poll(self)
      8 
      9     def poll(self):
---> 10         self.job.poll()
     11         self.x = None

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\job.pyc in poll(self)
     39       time.sleep(sleep)
     40       if sleep < 1.0: sleep += 0.1
---> 41       self._refresh_job_view()
     42       running = self._is_running()
     43     self._update_progress()

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\job.pyc in _refresh_job_view(self)
     52 
     53   def _refresh_job_view(self):
---> 54       jobs = H2OConnection.get_json(url_suffix="Jobs/" + self.job_key)
     55       self.job = jobs["jobs"][0] if "jobs" in jobs else jobs["job"][0]
     56       self.status = self.job["status"]

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.pyc in get_json(url_suffix, **kwargs)
    410     if __H2OCONN__ is None:
    411       raise ValueError("No h2o connection. Did you run `h2o.init()` ?")
--> 412     return __H2OCONN__._rest_json(url_suffix, "GET", None, **kwargs)
    413 
    414   @staticmethod

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.pyc in _rest_json(self, url_suffix, method, file_upload_info, **kwargs)
    419 
    420   def _rest_json(self, url_suffix, method, file_upload_info, **kwargs):
--> 421     raw_txt = self._do_raw_rest(url_suffix, method, file_upload_info, **kwargs)
    422     return self._process_tables(raw_txt.json())
    423 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.pyc in _do_raw_rest(self, url_suffix, method, file_upload_info, **kwargs)
    476 
    477     begin_time_seconds = time.time()
--> 478     http_result = self._attempt_rest(url, method, post_body, file_upload_info)
    479     end_time_seconds = time.time()
    480     elapsed_time_seconds = end_time_seconds - begin_time_seconds

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.pyc in _attempt_rest(self, url, method, post_body, file_upload_info)
    526 
    527     except requests.ConnectionError as e:
--> 528       raise EnvironmentError("h2o-py encountered an unexpected HTTP error:\n {}".format(e))
    529 
    530     return http_result

EnvironmentError: h2o-py encountered an unexpected HTTP error:
 ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

My hunch is that the cluster memory has only around 247.5 MB which is not enough to handle the model building hence aborted the connection to h2o. Here are the codes I used to initiate h2o:

```
 #initialization of h2o module
import subprocess as sp
import sys
import os.path as p

# path of h2o jar file
h2o_path = p.join(sys.prefix, "h2o_jar", "h2o.jar")

# subprocess to launch h2o
# the command can be further modified to include virtual machine parameters
sp.Popen("java -jar " + h2o_path)

# h2o.init() call to verify that h2o launch is successfull
h2o.init(ip="localhost", port=54321, size=1, start_h2o=False, enable_assertions=False, \
         license=None, max_mem_size_GB=4, min_mem_size_GB=4, ice_root=None)
```

and here is the returned status table:

[image]

Any ideas on the above would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest stable version of H2O, try again and let me know if the error persists?  http://www.h2o.ai/download/h2o/python  How big is your training dataset?

Comment: Hi Erin, thanks for your reply. The dataset i used is 8.72mb, my friend used the same dataset  and the same version of h2o, but she didn't have this error and her h2o allocated 800 plus mb for the cluster.

Comment: Your H2O cluster is quite small.  It looks like you tried to allocate 4GB in RAM for the H2O cluster, but you only got 247.5MB? Do you have 4GB of RAM free on your machine?

Comment: Yes Erin, that's what i was trying to do, my machine has 16gb of ram. But looks like it's not letting me force the allocation.

Comment: Just a quick update, i was able to use java -jar -Xmx1g h2o.jar to allocate 1gb of ram to h2o.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close out this question, I'll restate the solution mentioned in the comments above.  The user was able to resolve the issue by starting H2O from the command line with 1GB of memory using `java -jar -Xmx1g h2o.jar`, and then connected to the existing H2O server in Python using `h2o.init()`.

It's not clear to me why `h2o.init()` was not creating the correct size cluster using the `max_mem_size_GB` argument.  Regardless, this argument has been deprecated recently and replaced by another argument, `max_mem_size`, so it may no longer be an issue.